# Bitcoin core internal transfer problem

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-core-development

i have one big problem in bitcoin core internal transfer. to understand my question, please read my problem clearly.

**1) Let me explain you by providing example.**

- My one of the core account let's say "xyz" has 0.05 bitcoin balance. This is real balance.
- Now i am creating another two core account. "freebalance" & "dummy"
- now i am going to run this command move "freebalance" "dummy" 10000
  it will transfer 10000 btc to my new dummy account and freebalance account will have -10000
- i know that my "dummy" account has dummy balance that is 10000 BTC. i can not spend it on blockchain transactions. No issue for now.
- Now my xyz has 0.05 real bitcoin balance as i said earlier. and next i am transferring 5 BTC to my "xyz" account from "dummy" using internal transfer move command of bitcoin core.
- It will make my "xyz" account balance (0.05 real balance + 5 BTC dummy balance = 5.05 mixed balance)

> **Now the situation changes from here**
>   - whenever my internal transfer goes for "xyz" account to another account it will work good. but assume that i want to transfer 1 BTC
>   from that 5.05 BTC balance to any other blockchain address. I mean i
>   want to convert that "dummy" account generate balance to real one. So
>   we can send that transaction to our users directly.

**2) Another method or idea i have:**

- I have used json rpc api of bitcoin core.
- let's assume i have "abc" account with 0.10 balance. So is there any possibility in move api or sending api to stop balance part. like whenever i try to transfer amount 0.50 from "abc" to "xyz" account it should work.
  like this way-
- first of all when sending api calls in, we will send 0.50 btc to xyz, but before that process we want to stop balance part of bitcoin core that is checking & deducting 0.50 from "abc" account. This way i want to keep my 0.10 balance in "abc" as it is. and also want to deposit "xyz" account with 0.50 btc.

> In short words, i want to stop bitcoin core to run deduct task from my
>   core wallet account but run task of deposit or transfer easily without
>   any error. So i can send profit to my customers easily.

Anyone please help me to solve out 1) or 2) problem. at-least one. i'm hoping to get good helps from the community on this issue.

Comment: You should know that the entire concept of accounts and internal transfers in Bitcoin Core has been considered deprecated for more than two years.  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/7b782f5b01f4c2d906a28800d01ffd05ad257cbe As such it is not a good idea to design your application around it.

Answer (score -1):

Things you are trying to accomplish is you are try to transfer your bitcoin currency from one wallet to another wallet through internal bitcoind core system. whilst, you do not want to deduct balance. there is no api there which can prevent balance deduction.

bitcoind core has build their api if you tweak their code to prevent deduction of money. you can say you hacked bitcoin and your name will be breaking news! in theory you talk awesome, but practical way impossible.

Bitcoin virtual money is invented by satoshi nakamoto. also he can not do this things. if any person do transfer like you said. bitcoin will have zero value. 
reason: people will start installing core/generate new bitcoin daily/earn money/no mining forever. just earn money. practically your idea is worthless, impossible.

Comment: The question is about the virtual account system in Bitcoin Core, not how balance tracking works.

Comment: @PieterWuille Please read carefully what he wants. he said "In short words, i want to stop bitcoin core to run deduct task from my core wallet account but run task of deposit or transfer easily without any error. So i can send profit to my customers easily."

**he means, he don't want to deduct money with move command from "abc" he want balance as it is 0.10 , but he want to deposit 0.50 BTC money to another account "xyz". ** do you think it is possible? now read my reply again & tell me if i said anything wrong on it.